# java 10 compilaton Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac, java-9, java-10

I recently installed jdk10. I was doing normal code and it is not working.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Please see the code and Exception stacktrace.
As far as I understand there should be no reason for such behaviour.

```
import com.bean.College;

public class Student {

    interface Club {
        <T> T get(College<T> key);
    }

    private Club club;

    Student() {
        Object obj = club.get(new College<>() {});
    }
}
```

The imported `College` class is:

```
public class College<T> {
    int id;
    protected College() {
    }

    College(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
}
```

On compiling this the `javac` compiler crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1233)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:396)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitVarDef(Flow.java:987)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:956)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:396)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitBlock(Flow.java:995)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1020)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:396)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitMethodDef(Flow.java:962)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:866)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:396)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitClassDef(Flow.java:925)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:774)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:396)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:1325)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:1315)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow.analyzeTree(Flow.java:216)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1393)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1367)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:965)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:306)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:165)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

Comment: that is not my main function. it is javac main function. my code it only this much. I just compile it by javac.

Comment: In my Eclipse I get “'<>' cannot be used with anonymous classes” where you use `new College<>() {}`.

Comment: filename is same as classname

Comment: can you compile anything else with the installed jdk ? It doesn't look anything related to this class/code. I am just suspecting, if its an installation issue.

Comment: You found a bug in the Java compiler. Report it to Oracle/OpenJDK.

Comment: The only NullPointerException in the current code that I could see is `Object obj = club.get` if you instantiate the Student as `new Student()` only. Also, could you share how do you compile the code above(java version, IDE version etc.)

Comment: @nullpointer The `NullPointerException` doesn’t happen in the asker’s code. It happens in the Java compiler.

Comment: I have reproduced your crash using my javac 10.0.1 from Oracle and your source files. Agree with @JBNizet that you can do everyone a favour by reporting it to Oracle. Even if there is a bug in your program, the compiler shouldn’t crash.

Comment: Why the downvote, please? I find the question clear. The problem is both interesting and reproducible.

Comment: Reproduced the same compiler error with `javac 9.0.4`.

Comment: Thanks, @Oleksandr, for reporting. My javac 1.8.0_131 reports `reason: cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes` and doesn’t crash, so it seems the bug was introduced in Java 9.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thats why wanted to know the way the user was compiling their code. Now that I can read its reproducible, I am hoping this is explicitly by `javac` command line that the issue is reproduced. In which case, I agree the report would be useful :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a reported unresolved bug. The bug is planned to be resolved in jdk 11.

JDK-8203195-Anonymous class type inference results in NPE

```
Type:                 Bug
Status:               In Progress
Priority:             P2
Resolution:           Unresolved
Affects Version/s:    9, 10, 10.0.1, 11
Fix Version/s:        11
Component/s:          tools
Labels:               dcsfai reproducer-yes webbug 

Subcomponent:         javac
CPU:                  generic   
OS:                   generic
```

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8203195?filter=allopenissues

However, there is a work around mentioned in the bug description which states:

> Interestingly, changing A.java to do the following:
>     `Object baz => foo.foo(new B<Object>() {});`
>     or changing foo/B.java to the
>   following:
>
> ```
>  package foo;
>
>  public class B<T> {
>
>  B(int baz) {   }
>
>  protected B() {   } 
>  }
> ```
>
> results in a successful compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho the bug reports status is still open using java 11 fixes that issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and I couldn't find any solution. Even when I tried to build using java 11 (some say it is fixed there) it still failed with the same error.

But the error was just **MISLEADING**. After some changes in code and retries (I removed some code..), I found that the actual error was some missing libraries, which I added in the classpath and the build was successful!